# Update Parse deviceToken AFTER registration

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Currently I'm sitting with quite a few empty deviceToken fields. I figured out this is because there was an issue with adding groups before a installation object was created - it would block the subsequent creation efforts.

What I'm trying to do now is get that deviceToken again and update it in Parse but the problem is, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is never run again after the first time...

Any way to get the device token AFTER the initial call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`?

Comment: Are you registering for notifications each time your app runs?  The delegate method should be called each time you register.

Answer (score 0):

This does work for iOS 8:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` can be called repeatedly. Simply call the push registration code in your `AppDelegate.m`, in the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Here's what I use:

```
//Check for iOS 7 vs 8
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

That's it - if you call this each time, you'll get a delegate callback to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` on each load.